# How to write spark dataframe to impala database

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark-sql, impala

I use the following code to write the spark dataframe to impala through JDBC connection.

```
df.write.mode("append").jdbc(url="jdbc:impala://10.61.1.101:21050/test;auth=noSasl",table="t_author_classic_copy", pro)
```

But I get the following error: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found

then I change the mode:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").jdbc(url="jdbc:impala://10.61.1.101:21050/test;auth=noSasl",table="t_author_classic_copy", pro)
```

but it still get an error:

```
CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error
), Query: CREATE TABLE t_author_classic_copy1 (id TEXT NOT NULL, domain_id TEXT NOT NULL, pub_num INTEGER , cited_num INTEGER , rank DOUBLE PRECISION ).
```

Comment: *"No suitable driver found"* - quite explicit. Did you download the Impala JDBC driver from Cloudera web site, did you deploy it on the machine that runs Spark, did you add the JARs to the Spark CLASSPATH (e.g. using `spark.driver.extraClassPath` entry in `spark-defaults.conf`?

Comment: yes, I downloaded the driver from Cloudera, and it can use JDBC to read data from impala. but when I call the writefunction of dataframe, it occurred the error.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

spark-shell --driver-class-path ImpalaJDBC41.jar --jars ImpalaJDBC41.jar

```
val jdbcURL = s"jdbc:impala://192.168.56.101:21050;AuthMech=0"

val connectionProperties = new java.util.Properties()

import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode

sqlContext.sql("select * from my_users").write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(jdbcURL, "users", connectionProperties)
```

Comment: Please format your code as such, using proper indentation (4 spaces)

Comment: Actually, since the question was about a dataframe called `df`, the answer should refer to it for writing instead of the spark SQL table  `df.write.mode( ...`